# Extracting a part of value in a column which begins with '+' and ends with'=' using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a log file where there is a a pattern of strings i need to print.
(i am not giving the log details so putting forward a sample case).

```
cat file.txt
```

> 1234 is so so from 12+3=15
>
> 1235 is so so from 123+4=16
>
> 1236 is so so from 1543+4=16
>
> 1237 is so so from 13+4=16
>
> 1237 is so so from 13+5=16

the result value i am looking for is:-

> 1234 3
>
> 1235 4
>
> 1236 4
>
> 1237 9

I have tried using

```
cat file.txt |grep   " is so so from " | awk '{print $1,substr($6,3,1);}' |awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for(i in a) print i,a[i]
```

but this gives only when the 6th column have a constant string.

to make it dynamic, i am seeking help where i can get a part of string having "+" value before it and "=" at its other end.

I am seeking help where i can get a part of string having "+" value before it and "=" at its other end.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you input file is, so I'm assuming my answer on this `file.txt`:

```
1234 is so so from 12+3=15
1235 is so so from 123+4=16
1236 is so so from 1543+4=16
1237 is so so from 13+4=16
1237 is so so from 13+5=16
```

So with such file as input, here's how I'd target those values

```sh
cat file.txt \
  | grep -Po '^[0-9]+.*\+\d'
  | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)[^+]+\+([0-9]+)/\1 \2/'
  | awk '{ a[$1] += $2 } END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] }'
```

How does it work?

1. `grep` to extract the portion we care about
2. `sed` to remove the in between noise
3. `awk` to compute the needed sum result

---

Another solution: Just a simple line, albeit a bit not so simple to follow..

```sh
cat file.txt \
  | awk 'match($0, /^([0-9]+)[^+]+\+([0-9]+)/, m) { a[m[1]] += m[2] } END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] }'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `awk` and a regular expression to extract the interesting columns?

```
cat file.txt | awk 'match($0, /([0-9]+)[^+]*\+([0-9]+)=.*/, a) { print a[1], a[2] }'
```

yields

```
1234 3
1235 4
1236 4
1237 4
1237 5
```

**Edit:** Summing up the second column if the first one is identical is shown by @eridal:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'match($0, /([0-9]+)[^+]*\+([0-9]+)=.*/, a) { print a[1], a[2] }' | awk '{ a[$1] += $2 } END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] }'
```

yields

```
1234 3
1235 4
1236 4
1237 9
```

Comment: haha we submitted the same answer!! great minds think alike :)

Comment: thank you so much. its works perfectl. just curious to understand how this -match($0, /([0-9]+)[^+]*\+([0-9]+)=.*/, a) works. please explain.

Comment: The first parameter to match is just the input line. 
The second parameter to match is a regular expression, that searches for
at least one digit ("[0-9]+"), followed by an arbitrary number of characters which are not a plus sign ("[^+]*"), then a plus sign ("\+"), again an arbitrary number of digits ("[0-9]+"), an equal sign ("=") and an arbitrary number of arbitrary characters (".*"). You might have recognized that both digit-blocks are surrounded by braces. This groups them and puts them into a (third parameter to match). Afterwards, the groups are available as a[1] and a[2].